# How to read custom Microsoft Office properties in a Google Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, properties, cpu-word

I'm searching for an Appscript function that allow to read/access the Microsoft office properties existing in a word document (.docx, .docm formats).
These properties are usually visible in the custom.xml file of the openxml format, but I don't  know if we can access this information with Appscript.

Please, could you give me some help ?

Thank you very much.
Nicolas

Comment: Are you asking how a Google Apps script can [parse XML data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)?

Comment: Not exactly. I just want to know if it's possible to access the Microsoft custom office properties with Google Apps script. A .docx file is composed of multiple XML files (for document content /text, properties, images, relation in the file...). This is the concept of openXML format. I know we can access the content of a docx file using blobs, but I don't know if it's possible for the properties

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with that. When you [unzip](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities) your Word document, do you see the `custom.xml` file somewhere in the resulting directory?

Comment: I will test it and keep you posted. But i would like to not create/extract content in a drive folder to access the information. Thank you for this first proposal .

Comment: Understood - you can edit your question to clarify that. (I don't know of any way to stream the Word doc's compressed data and extract the XML file, using _only_ the tools in the Google Apps toolset - but maybe someone else will know how, if you phrase the question that way).